# How to convert string to JSON?

Tags: json

How to convert the following string into Json which contains some special characters? I want some specific notification URL and values for verification.

```
colombiaadCallback("[{\"snippet\":\"\",\"adSlot\":\"208039\",\"section\":\"0\",\"position\":\"1\",\"ip\":\"223.165.29.225\",\"success\":-1,\"cs\":[{\"c\":\"http:\/\/ads.yahoo.com\/cms\/v1?esig=2~0e5920937f6aadb48bff63caeaefd5a0b961c753&nwid=1117471&sigv=1\",\"id\":16116},{\"c\":\"http:\/\/ade.clmbtech.com\/uid\/sync.htm?pid=19844&xid=<SSO User Id>\",\"id\":19844}],\"fpc\":\"ade1eb41-40a7-4937-9179-86ed1641f77e-10otg~1\"},{\"snippet\":\"\",\"adSlot\":\"208039\",\"section\":\"0\",\"position\":\"2\",\"ip\":\"223.165.29.225\",\"success\":-1,\"cs\":[{\"c\":\"http:\/\/ads.yahoo.com\/cms\/v1?esig=2~0e5920937f6aadb48bff63caeaefd5a0b961c753&nwid=1117471&sigv=1\",\"id\":16116},{\"c\":\"http:\/\/ade.clmbtech.com\/uid\/sync.htm?pid=19844&xid=<SSO User Id>\",\"id\":19844}],\"fpc\":\"ade1eb41-40a7-4937-9179-86ed1641f77e-10otg~1\"},{\"snippet\":\"\",\"adSlot\":\"208038\",\"section\":\"0\",\"position\":\"1\",\"ip\":\"223.165.29.225\",\"success\":-1,\"cs\":[{\"c\":\"http:\/\/ads.yahoo.com\/cms\/v1?esig=2~0e5920937f6aadb48bff63caeaefd5a0b961c753&nwid=1117471&sigv=1\",\"id\":16116},{\"c\":\"http:\/\/ade.clmbtech.com\/uid\/sync.htm?pid=19844&xid=<SSO User Id>\",\"id\":19844}],\"fpc\":\"ade1eb41-40a7-4937-9179-86ed1641f77e-10otg~1\"},{\"snippet\":\"\",\"adSlot\":\"208039\",\"section\":\"0\",\"position\":\"3\",\"ip\":\"223.165.29.225\",\"success\":-1,\"cs\":[{\"c\":\"http:\/\/ads.yahoo.com\/cms\/v1?esig=2~0e5920937f6aadb48bff63caeaefd5a0b961c753&nwid=1117471&sigv=1\",\"id\":16116},{\"c\":\"http:\/\/ade.clmbtech.com\/uid\/sync.htm?pid=19844&xid=<SSO User Id>\",\"id\":19844}],\"fpc\":\"ade1eb41-40a7-4937-9179-86ed1641f77e-10otg~1\"}]")
```

Comment: please use code formatting in your post, tell us what you've tried so far (have you searched the web?), and give us details about your environment. e.g. what language you're using. also, converting the above to JSON doesn't make sense. do you perhaps want to _parse_ the above _as_ JSON?

Comment: Please format your JSON so it is readable - [tools are available](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).

Answer (score 1):

Try use JSON.parse();

```
var newJson = JSON.parse(myString);
```

In your case I set a variable with your sample code and everything is working fine:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
 0:Object
 adSlot:"208039"
 cs:Array[2]0:Object
    c:"http://ads.yahoo.com/cms/v1?esig=2~0e5920937f6aadb48bff63caeaefd5a0b961c753&nwid=1117471&sigv=1"
    id:16116
    __proto__:Object.......
```

Comment: The above mentioned string contains some urls like "http:\/\/ade.clmbtech.com\/uid\/sync.htm?pid=19844&xid=<SSO User Id>\",\"id\":19844}],\"fpc\":\"ade1eb41-40a7-4937-9179-86ed1641f77e-10otg~1\"}     which contains some special characters like "/"   because of this I am not able to parse the JSON. please help me to parse this JSON completely

Comment: I don't know what can be wrong because I put your sample in a variable and then parse to JSON without any kind of error.